# Detect Materializecss tab change

Tags: angularjs, tabs, materialize

I am using Angular-materialize tabs and need to detect when a user changes tabs so that I can call a separate function on tab change (some data on each tab pane is not automatically loaded) Is this possible without using ng-click?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Materialize does not provide a way to bind a function to tab change event.
Therefore, you have to use `ng-click` in `<a>` tag or bind a event handler:

```
$('ul.tabs').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    //Your code
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense.

Comment: Does not work this method. Because, fire click event before change. And could not receive correct value.

Comment: Yes indeed, i'm looking for a way to bind it afterward, maybe a timeout could work but it feels bad

Answer (score 3):

2 way to get "tab" click event

use onShow: new_tab_show_callback(your callback function name)
[onShow callback function](http://materializecss.com/tabs.html)

```
 // init materialize tab
  var elem = $('.tabs')


  var options = {duration: 600, onShow: new_tab_show_callback}
  var init_tabs = M.Tabs.init(elem, options);
  var instance_tabs = M.Tabs.getInstance(elem);


      //----- new tab clicked -----
      function new_tab_show_callback (){

            console.log('showing tab +++++ ' + instance_tabs.index)



      }
```

anther old way is you set id for tab tag

```
li(class='tab col s4' id='tag_search')
```

then

```
 $("#tag_search").click(function() {

     console.log('************* search tab *********** clicked **************')
        })
```